# SQLite syntax for multiple tables

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

This is my syntax to show multiple tables but there is no information. Can anyone tell me where am I wrong?

```
$sql = "SELECT 'i'.*,
        't'.'name' AS 'type_name', 'c'.'name' AS 'client_name'
        FROM 'items' 'i'
        JOIN 'types' 't', 'clients' 'c'
        ON 't'.'id' = 'i'.'type', 'c'.'id' = 'i'.'client'
        ORDER BY 'i'.'date' DESC";

$result = $objDb->query($sql);
if (!$result) {

    throw new PDOException("Error Processing Request");

}
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$items = $result->fetchAll();
$sql = "SELECT 'clients', 'types'
        FROM 'items', 'clients'
        ORDER BY 'id'";

$result = $objDb->query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    throw new PDOException("Error Processing Request");

}
```

Comment: They're just short aliases for the full table names so you don't have to type the full names everywhere.

Comment: And if I want to select multiple tables as "clients" do I need to right as JOIN 'types' 't', 'clients' 'c' ON 't'.'id', 'c'.id = 'i'.'type'?

Comment: The full syntax is `FROM tablename AS alias`. It would be clearer if you included the `AS`. Also, remove those single quotes - they make the place look untidy.

Comment: If you want to add a third table it would be like what you already have for types, placing it before the `ORDER BY` like this ---   `JOIN clients AS c ON c.id = i.type` (although I can't say what columns you should use in the join).